# Android Koin DI - Sharing ViewModel with multiple implementations

Tags: android, koin

I have a viewModel like:

```
abstract class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
   abstract fun onTextUpdated(text: String)
   abstract val liveData: LiveData<String>
}
```

Which has 2 implementations like:

```
class MyViewModelOne : MyViewModel() {
    override fun onTextUpdated(text: String) { // Do stuff }
    override val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
}

class MyViewModelTwo : MyViewModel() {
    override fun onTextUpdated(text: String) { // Do stuff }
    override val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

Which are each used in their own seperate fragments, let's call them `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` for the sake of demonstration.

`FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` both share the requirement to ask the user to enter some text via a dialog added to the host activity when the user taps a "Add Note" button. Let's call this dialog `FragmentThree` for the sake of demonstration. The result of this dialog (a string) should be shared with the parent fragment via the `onTextUpdated` function on either `FragmentOne` or `FragmentTwo` respectively, depending upon which route the user took through the app, when the dialog is dismissed.

Obviously, I only want to implement the `FragmentThree` dialog once, as it will look the same and have the same behaviour for both the `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` use cases.

Therefore, I decided in the `FragmentThree` implementation to make use of Koins `by sharedViewModel` delegate, to share the viewModel injected in with the parent scope (the activity level). Obviously, because I don't know which implementation of `MyViewModel` will be there, because either `FragmentOne` or `FragmentTwo` could have lead to this point, I am referencing the base abstract class `MyViewModel` instead, assuming that Koin will be able to resolve this at run time.

However, when I run the code, the app crashes with:

```
2022-04-12 09:51:52.422 3607-3607/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 3607
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.example.test.MyViewModel'. Check your definitions!
```

In my Koin module, where I am creating the definitions of what interfaces/abstract classes map to which implementations, I have correctly setup definitions for both of the implementations of `MyViewModel`, and the `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` code which uses this view model via the `by sharedViewModel` delegate works fine as I also stipulate a `qualifier` for each of them, in both the module definitions and the fragments themselves, like so:

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModel<MyViewModel>(
        named("myViewModelOne")
    ) {
        MyViewModelOne()
    }
    
    viewModel<MyViewModel>(
        named("myViewModelTwo")
    ) {
        MyViewModelTwo()
    }
}
```

And then, in `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` where the implementations are used, similarly:

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by sharedViewModel<MyViewModel>(
        named("myViewModelOne")
    )
    
    ...
}

class FragmentTwo : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by sharedViewModel<MyViewModel>(
        named("myViewModelTwo")
    )

    ...
}
```

And finally, in `FragmentThree` where I am wanting Koin to determine the implementation dynamically based upon the parent fragments view model implementation:

```
class FragmentThree : DialogFragment() {
    private val viewModel by sharedViewModel<MyViewModel>()
    
    ...
}
```

So, my question is; is there someway I can share the view model from either `FragmentOne` or `FragmentTwo` via referencing it's base class in the `by sharedViewModel` delegate in `FragmentThree` without also qualifying which implementation to use (because I want it to use whichever implementation is currently active on it's parent fragment).